# Friendly URLs from Query String

Tags: .htaccess

My Url's currently look like this

http://audioflare.io/charts?category=drum-bass

but I want them to look like this

http://audioflare.io/charts/drum-bass/

http://audioflare.io/charts/house/

http://audioflare.io/charts/deep-house/

I know its done within the htaccess file, but how?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Use what @starkeen has said. Will work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

In htaccess in the document root :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^charts/([^./]+)/?$ /charts?category=$1 [L]
```

This rewrites **/charts/foobar** to **/charts?category=foobar** .

Remove **charts/** from the rewrite pattern if you are going to place this in **/charts/.htaccess** .